# Length of size_t not correct?

Tags: c

`theMessageMaxLength` keeps giving me a value of `4` even if the length is larger than 4. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? It is of type `size_t` and I don't have it declared anywhere, rather it is just a value being passed in as such:

```
place_value(int task, struct PDB *llist, char *theMessage, size_t theMessageMaxLength)
```

The above method is being called as follows:

```
place_value(task, llist, theMessage, sizeof(theMessage));
```

I'm assuming this is where the length gets set to 4, however, shouldn't it be set to something larger if my message is larger? How would I increase the size so it's not just 4...?

and then used like this within the function it is being passed into:

```
strncpy(llist->data1, theMessage, theMessageMaxLength);
llist->data1[theMessageMaxLength] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing `sizeof()` with `strlen()`.

`sizeof(theMessage)` will only give you the size of a `char*` which is a pointer - (4 bytes in your case). If you want the length of the string, you'll need to use `strlen(theMessage)` instead.

```
place_value(task, llist, theMessage, strlen(theMessage));
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(theMessage)` is literally same as `sizeof(char *)`.  Perhaps you were confused with the situation below:

```
char theMessage[1024];

/* ... some code here ...*/

printf("sizeof(theMessage): %zd\n", sizeof(theMessage));
```

If you allocate memory for `theMessage`, then you should provide its size.

EDIT: As a side node, you may be interested in `strndup` which allocates memory automatically and appends a NULL character at the end to the destination string.  But of course, you'll have to be careful and don't forget to free it.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring the size of a pointer, which is 4 (on 32-bit platform).